# kubernetes node cannot connect to api-server: dial tcp: lookup kubernetes.default.svc on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

Tags: kubernetes

I've built 3 nodes on linux academy. On the control plane I can see 3 nodes running. On either of the two worker nodes I try to run `kubectl get nodes`. Initially I was prompted that `KUBERNETES_MASTER` was not set.

Inside the worker nodes, I've tried setting this to the server value found in `/kube/config` in master. So in worker node: `export KUBERNETES_MASTER=https://1.2.3.4:6443`. When I try this and then try again `kubectl get nodes` I get `Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

I've also tried setting to `export KUBERNETES_MASTER=https://kubernetes.default.svc` in the worker nodes. When I try this and then try `kubectl get nodes` I get `Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup kubernetes.default.svc on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use cluster DNS names from inside pods, not from the nodes directly. As for the cert issue, your kube config file will generally include the CA used for API TLS.

Comment: thanks for the info. I didn't think `kubernetes.default.svc` would work but I wasn't sure what else to try. I can view my CA in the config file but can you point me to where I need to use this in the worker node?

Comment: Why are you trying to use kubectl on a node?

Answer (score 1):

We usually save configurations of `kubectl` to a file at `~/.kube/config`, which contains both the master endpoint and certificate. You can easily copy it from masters.

And, the FQDN of `kubernetes.default.svc` is `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` assuming your cluster domain is `cluster.local`. This domain name is set for workloads that are deployed in
clusters and need to access the API server. Such that, the domain name is designed to be resolved only in clusters by `kube-dns`.

For processes out of clusters, the hostname or IP address/VIP is often used as the endpoint of the API server.

Answer (score 0):

I am working behind a corporate proxy. In my case, the reason was the wrong config (wrong nameserver) in /etc/resolv.conf.

Updating the nameserver solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think, we receive this error, if one of our resource, resides in different location or different region