# kubernetes kubectl from another node to control plane: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes

I've setup 3 nodes on a cluster following https://linuxacademy.com/blog/containers/building-a-three-node-kubernetes-cluster-quick-guide/. I have all the visible from the control plane. When I try to run:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

from a worker node however, I get:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
```

If I try:

```
kubectl get nodes --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
```

I get:

```
the server doesn't have a resource type "nodes"
```

The api-server logs:

```
Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure",
"message":"pods \"kube-apiserver-user1c.mylabserver.com\" not found",
"reason":"NotFound","details":{"name":"kube-apiserver-user1c.mylabserver.com",
"kind":"pods"},"code":404}
```

`kube-apiserver-user1c.mylabserver.com` very much does exist, however

Logs for api-server show:

```
http: TLS handshake error from worker_node_ip:37596: remote error: tls: bad certificate`
```

So it very much looks like it doesn't like the certificate. I haven't been able to solve this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubernetes node cannot connect to api-server: dial tcp: lookup kubernetes.default.svc on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919254/kubernetes-node-cannot-connect-to-api-server-dial-tcp-lookup-kubernetes-defaul)

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions on the same thing. `kubectl` is not generally used from nodes and you probably don't have a valid config in place for it. Use it from your workstation, as is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I followed steps form this article and checked this lab on `LinuxAcademy`.

In article which was posted on `Posted on March 20, 2019` when `kubernetes` version was `~1.12` which is quite old (current version is `1.18`).

However in article, they are using `packages.cloud.google.com` which downloads latest version of `kubectl` and `kubeadm`. According to this article, you will have latest version of docker(19.03), kubeadm(1.18), kubectl(1.18) but link to `CNI` in article is to `Flannel` which was compatible with `Kubernetes 1.12`.

If you followed this article these days you would get error like:

```
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/bc79dd1505b0c8681ece4de4c0d86c5cd2643275/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

This issue occurs because between Kubernetes 1.15 and 1.16 there was huge chage in `apiVersion`.

In LinuxAcademy, they used proper version to `Flannel` CNI which was `Kubernetes` and `Kubeadm` in version 1.12.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y kubelet=1.12.7-00 kubeadm=1.12.7-00 kubectl=1.12.7-00
```

For current version of Kubectl you should use [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) to apply `CNIs`

Regarding issue with certificates, when you use command:

```
$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

you are getting all defaults settings (also certs). More information you can find in [Kbueadm Initialisation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/).
After that you should get `join command` which should be use on `worker nodes` to add them to cluster. After that, it should automatically configure node. For more information about `Join` can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/).

Good lab would be to try install kubeadm based on [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

Last thing I want to mention is that, as you have `1 master` node and `2 worker` nodes. You should execute commands only on master node. Worker nodes shouldn't run `kubectl`.